# How well do users understand the word “Filter”?

Tags: mobile, filter, copywriting

How well do users understand the term “Filter” when used as the label for an interface control?

Ideally the label would reflect specifically what you're filtering by - “date” or ”status” for example, but where multiple filters are required in a small area I would prefer to use a single button to display the full list of filter options.

We're also considering “Refine” which is used by Amazon and eBay but also seems a little more ambiguous than I'd like and “Sort & filter” which would include the sorting options.

We intend to user test the possibilities but I imagine it's something that's been tested many times before.

[image: Sort & Filter command]

Answer (score 2):

While I am not aware of any specific research on text options for this functionality, two things come to mind:

**Imply meaning via context**

Are you able to adjust the overall layout? If so, I suggest moving the "Sort & Filter" box closer to the "175 Results" heading to imply via proximity that the sort/filter actions apply to the results.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frfyVg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The label text may be less important if the box gains additional context next to the search result title.

**Grouping**

Sort and filter offer very different functionality. Could you separate them into two buttons, or must they remain grouped? I presume using "Sort by:" (and "Filter By:") followed by a dropdown of options would be very clear.